# How to make R Studio Server load time faster?

Tags: r, nginx, jupyter-notebook, rstudio-server

I have RStudio Server with this setup:

```
1- It's accessible through the terminal in Jupyter notebooks
2- It's hosted with a Kube app with a Docker image and I use NGINX
```

I have a script to start from my instance from the terminal in Jupyter.

It's connected to a machine that has a lot of memory and harddrive space.

The steps of the scripts are basically:

```
1- Download R
2- Downloads five R packages
3- Build nginx
3- Create docker instance
```

The output will be a url for rstudio server and when I load the URL I usually have to wait ~20 minutes to access R.

It either shows me a grey loading screen or it loads RStudio Server but I can't do anything (it'll indicate a running process).

How do I make this load time more like 1-2 minutes instead of 15-20 minutes? What might cause this delay?

Comment: "Download important packages" How many and how large are these? Are these R packages?

Comment: It downloads five important R packages, like tidyverse and lubridate

Comment: Well, tidyverse (in my opinion not important at all) has a humongous dependency tree. Try without installing these packages to confirm but I'd expect this to take most of the time (in particular if they are built from source).

Comment: Most of the load time takes place after the R packages are downloaded since I can watch that happen from terminal. That process usually takes ~1 minute

Comment: Are you downloading windows binaries? Otherwise, these packages have to be build by R and that is time consuming.

Comment: I'm running `RUN echo "install.packages('tidyverse')" | R` in the script to initialize the docker image

Comment: OK, and I assume this is not a windows or mac OS. Thus, the packages have to be build from source.

Comment: Yep, that's a fair assumption

Comment: I come back to my suggestion above. Try the process without installing extra packages. That should be significantly faster. Doesn't solve your problem though if you need these packages.

Comment: Thanks! I tried it without installing the packages and it's still very slow